# Updated MS Access DB not working without any error

Tags: c#, ms-access, textbox, listbox, updates

i create a program which load the data to listbox from ms-access, and create some action like add, update and delete the item..i got the item inserted and deleted properly. but i do not know what should i do to make this update working because the update query just won't fire up when the button is clicked(the item not getting updated on database), just to let ya know i got the messagebox.show below this code working like it should be.

```
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Item SET ITEM = @ITEM, ITEM_DESC = @ITEM_DESC, PRICE = @PRICE, QUANTITY = @QUANTITY WHERE ID = @ID", GetConnection());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(txtItemID.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITEM", txtItemName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITEM_DESC", txtItemDesc.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRICE", Convert.ToDouble(txtItemPrice2.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QUANTITY", Convert.ToInt32(txtItemQuantity.Value));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your parameters are in the wrong order, as far as I can see, they must be in the same order as the query. The names are completely irrelevant except as prompts for the progammer, they are not used in any real sense. This means that the wrong value for ID is being used.

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Item SET ITEM = @ITEM,  
          ITEM_DESC = @ITEM_DESC, PRICE = @PRICE, QUANTITY = @QUANTITY 
          WHERE ID = @ID", GetConnection());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITEM", txtItemName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITEM_DESC", txtItemDesc.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRICE", Convert.ToDouble(txtItemPrice2.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QUANTITY", Convert.ToInt32(txtItemQuantity.Value));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(txtItemID.Text));
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: so..thats the only thing that make it wont execute..lol my bad..thanks